# Wasm-rust and postgres

Tags: postgresql, rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

is there a way to get data from a database in postgres  using wasm?.  I'd tried to get it using a library in rust but I got some errore when I build the package using "wasm-pack building--target web". The idea is to build a function in lib.rs file that return data from a db. I have the below code inside lib.rs:

```
use postgres::{Client, Error, NoTls};
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;
...

struct Author {
    _id: i32,
    name: String,
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn select_name(name: &String) -> Result<(), Error> {
    let mut client = Client::connect("postgresql://user:1234@localhost:5432/db", NoTls)?;    
    for row in client.query(
        "SELECT id, name FROM author WHERE name = $1",
        &[&name],
    )? {
        let author = Author {
            _id: row.get(0),
            name: row.get(1),
        };
        println!(
            "Select_Name => Author {} :",
            author.name
        );
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

but I get some errors:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `crate::sys::IoSourceState`
error[E0432]: unresolved import `crate::sys`
...
```

Comment: You do know that Postgres runs server-side and wasm runs on browser? Where will this run?

Comment: I know, that's why I am asking, Wasm converts rust functions to be run on the brower

Comment: That will not be possible. You need to separate the logic and use `http` eg in https://github.com/chidea/actix-yew-live-tmpl

Comment: Where will this wasm file be running, in the browser or in node? If in browser then no you can't connect to the db because you can't connect to the db directly from the browser. If it's node then you need to import from the js side an object/function that will act as a proxy which execute your queries https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/examples/import-js.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible directly (as Njuguna Mureithi rightly wrote) but it can be circumvented.

We can use the project: https://github.com/PostgREST/postgrest
and expose the API to our sql server.

We download the latest version of postgrest
https://github.com/PostgREST/postgrest/releases/tag/v9.0.0
in case of Linux we unpack

`tar -xf postgrest-v9.0.0-linux-static-x64.tar.xz`

then run help

`./postgrest -h`

create a configuration file for ./postgrest

`postgrest -e > cfg.psqlrest`

change the user and password for the database in the configuration file.
e.g. with

`db-uri = "postgres://user:pasword@localhost:5432/dbname"`

to your dbname database access user:pasword configuration

`db-uri = "postgres://postgres:zaqwsxc@localhost:5432/dbname"`

and run the server which will issue the api to our postgres

`./postgrest cfg.psqlrest`

The address http://localhost:3000 will start accessing the database dbname, which must be created in the database server beforehand.

Here is a description of the libraries needed to call the query using the API.

https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/examples/fetch.html

examples of API
https://postgrest.org/en/stable/api.html